# Phobos-Range Compatible Fixed-Dimensional Vector

Tags: range, d, linear-algebra, fixed-size-types

What is the most clever way of implementing a fixed-dimensional vector in D that is compatible with the `RandomAccessRange` [interface](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#isRandomAccessRange) in Phobos? Do I have to reimplement all the members `opIndex`, `length` etc or is the cleverer way through delegation, alias this or template mixins? I've been looking at a couple of fixed-size vector structs on github D projects but none seem to care about being compatible with Phobos ranges. **Update**: Is just read that containers should be reference types so I guess this isn't the way to do it in D right?

Comment: convention in std.container is that the `opSlice()´ is used to get the range over which you can iterate, which type of range is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your vector has continuous internal storage then you can just return a slice of that data from `opSlice()`:

```
struct Vector
{
    private real[4] data;

    auto opSlice() { return data[]; }
}
```

Containers don't have to be reference types, but either way using `opSlice` is the usual way to get a range from a container.